# Resolving a path in clustered Actor system

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have an hierarchy of 3 actors:
`SM -> R -> W`
SM - Service Manager
R - router
W - worker

SM creates the R actor that in turn created actor W which is deployed on a remote node.

Creation of Actor W takes some time because it gathers information from external services so a few seconds delay is normal. Thus in `preStart()` I want to send a message from W to SM that init is complete and it is fully operational.

I've tried to reach the SM actor from W this way:

```
val myCreatorServiceManagerActorPath = self.path.parent.parent
context.actorSelection(myCreatorServiceManagerActorPath) ! RegisteredServiceWorker(serviceName)
```

All of those messages goes to the deadLetter inbox.
Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't the localization be transparent?
What is the proper way of contacting the SM actor?

If it's of any help here is the dead-letter-log

```
monitor [INFO] [03/28/2014 11:34:49.253] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] [akka://application/remote/akka.tcp/application@127.0.0.1:2558/user/ServiceManager] Message [pl.mlife.mcloud.runner.common.ServiceRuntimeActor$RegisteredServiceWorker] from Actor[akka://application/remote/akka.tcp/application@127.0.0.1:2558/user/ServiceManager/sample/c3#-1356554194] to Actor[akka://application/remote/akka.tcp/application@127.0.0.1:2558/user/ServiceManager] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `R` pass `SM` to `W` in its constructor.  Then send directly to `W` without needing to use `actorSelection`.

Comment: Idea is good. Still it does not tell why the heck this is not working. By design, localization transparency, should help with this.